# How do I automatically bind mount on boot in a non-root encrypted home directory?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, fstab, disk-encryption

I want to bind mount a directory within my home when I log on. The line in fstab would be

```
/foo/bar /home/me/wherever none bind 0 0
```

The trouble is my home directory is encrypted, so it has to happen after I log in. The problem is my login scripts don't have permission to run mount.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Everything you need is already built into mount.

The `user` option will allow non-root users to mount it
also add `noauto` to stop mount attempts during system startup.

```
/foo/bar /home/me/wherever none user,noauto,bind 0 0
```

Comment: Tried that. Nothing mounts, but it also doesn't interrupt the boot with an error as it did before. Will there be a log of this?

Comment: yeah, you have to add the command to mount it in your log-on script.

Answer (score 0):

[super](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/super/) can run scripts setuid root. Try it. http://www.ucolick.org/~will/RUE/super/super.1.html.

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer super over sudo